# Multiple INNER JOIN with WHERE CLAUSE - 4 Tables

Tags: mysql

i have small problem with join. i have 4 tables.

**as_ticmat** Tbl is joining **as_mat** Tbl so i can get **name** column from **as_mat** Tbl same thing with
**as_sertic** Tbl is joining **as_ser** Tbl but only with one condition. which is from  **as_ticmat** Tbl the  ***tic_id*** column must be equal to 1 as well from     **as_sertic** Tbl the **tic_id** column must be equal to 1

here are my  tables

```
mysql> TBL: as_ticmat;
+--------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| ticmat_id    |  mat_id |  tic_id |  matprice |
+--------------+---------+---------+-----------+
|            1 |       1 |       1 |     20.00 |
|            2 |       2 |       1 |     30.00 |
|            3 |       3 |       4 |    640.00 |
|            4 |       4 |       4 |    500.00 |
+--------------+---------+---------+-----------+

mysql> TBL: as_mat;
+-----------+-------------------+
| mat_id    | name              |
+-----------+-------------------+
|         1 | XXXX - XXXXX - XX |
|         2 | XXXX - XXXXX - XX |
|         3 | XXXX - XXXXX - XX |
|         4 | XXXX - XXXXX - XX |
+-----------+-------------------+

mysql> TBL: as_sertic;
+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| sertic_id    |  tic_id |  ser_id |  mec_id | rate    |
+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|            1 |       1 |       2 |       4 |  500.00 |
|            2 |       1 |       3 |       4 | 1000.00 |
|            3 |       4 |       4 |       4 |  420.00 |
|            4 |       4 |       5 |       4 |  420.00 |
+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+

mysql> TBL: as_ser;
+------------+----------+--------+
| ser_id     | name     | price  |
+------------+----------+--------+
|          1 | XXX XXXX |  50.00 |
|          2 | XXX XXXX |  50.00 |
|          3 | XXX XXXX | 250.00 |
|          4 | XXX XXXX | 210.00 |
|          5 | XXX XXXX | 210.00 |
+------------+----------+--------+
```

Here is my query.

```
SELECT `as_ticmat`.`tickmat_id`,
       `as_ticmat`.`mate_id`,
       `as_ticmat`.`mateprice`,
       `as_sertic`.`sertic_id`,
       `as_sertic`.`ser_id`,

SUM        (as_tictmat.matprice`) AS `mat`
SUM        (as_sertic.rate)       AS `ser`
FROM       `as_ticmat`
INNER JOIN `as_sertic`
ON         `as_sertic`.`ser_id` = `as_ser`.`ser_id`
INNER JOIN `as_mate`
ON         `as_ticmat`.`mat_id` = `as_mat`.`mat_id`
WHERE      `tic_id` = 1
```

Comment: You state that you have a small problem but I don't see any question?

Comment: Ohh sorry, forgot to mention my problem. there is Sql error.. i just can't get it done

Comment: Does this query need a `group by` clause? Or are you content with a one-row result?

Comment: yeah , i think i will use group by clause, once i get it done...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query had several spelling errors, a missing comma and also you never joined the `as_ser` table. I think the corrected query should look like this:

```
SELECT as_ticmat.ticmat_id,
       as_ticmat.mat_id,
       as_ticmat.matprice,
       as_sertic.sertic_id,
       as_sertic.ser_id,
       SUM(as_ticmat.matprice) AS mat,
       SUM(as_sertic.rate)     AS ser
FROM       as_ticmat    
INNER JOIN as_sertic
ON         as_sertic.ser_id = as_ticmat.tic_id
INNER JOIN as_ser
ON         as_sertic.ser_id = as_ser.ser_id
INNER JOIN as_mat
ON         as_ticmat.mat_id = as_mat.mat_id
WHERE      as_ticmat.tic_id = 1
```

All these errors were easy to find from the error message that appeared...

With most SQL databases you would also need a `group by` clause at the end since you're using an aggregate function (MySQL is an exception in that it won't require a group by clause, but you won't get the result you would if you grouped the data) in which case you should add

```
GROUP BY 
       as_ticmat.ticmat_id,
       as_ticmat.mat_id,
       as_ticmat.matprice,
       as_sertic.sertic_id,
       as_sertic.ser_id
```

at the end of the query.

Comment: Ohh, i did't saw, even thought i have check the query couple of times. Thanks " JPW " i will check the query hope it works..

Comment: Thanks pro..it's works. it was some typos , i hate that... :)